# Cannot connect to pg database from ec2 instance using node-postgres

Tags: node.js, postgresql, amazon-ec2, node-postgres

I am trying to query a pg database from a nodejs express app hosted on ec2 instance. I am using `node-postgres` library. However, I am getting this error:

```
error: no pg_hba.conf entry for host "xxx.xx.xx.xxx", user "xyz", database "db_name", SSL off
at Connection.parseE (/home/ec2-user/express/node_modules/pg/lib/connection.js:553:11)
at Connection.parseMessage (/home/ec2-user/express/node_modules/pg/lib/connection.js:378:19)
at Socket.<anonymous> (/home/ec2-user/express/node_modules/pg/lib/connection.js:119:22)
at Socket.emit (events.js:182:13)
at Socket.EventEmitter.emit (domain.js:442:20)
at addChunk (_stream_readable.js:283:12)
at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:264:11)
at Socket.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:219:10)
at TCP.onread (net.js:639:20)
```

Now I understand that this might be a straightforward issue. My understanding is that the pg_hba.conf file on the postgres server allows only `0.0.0.0` ip's to connect, because when I run the same application from my local machine with mac os, it works perfectly fine.

I tried several ways like having an nginx proxy, adding ssl connection etc. But nothing seems to work out.

I would be grateful if someone can help me shed some light on this problem. Totally blocked!

Comment: Maybe you should add local address be 127.0.0.1  in your pg_hba.conf? This does mark local connection as far as I know... try adding it as `host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            trust` and see if it works

Comment: @Jorge_Freitas a quick question about this. I am simply trying to connect to an external pg database with some credentials provided. So how can modifying the instance's pg_hba.conf file affect the connection?

Comment: I see now I misunderstood the question... so you are trying to connect from a different machine. From [PostgreSQL documentation][1], `pg_hba.conf` controls client authentication. Therefore if a connection is being attempted by an address not listed there it will get refused. Instead of `127.0.0.1/32`, add your remote machine's IP/mask and try again. Also, make sure the user you are using has the `CONNECT` privilege.


  [1]: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/auth-pg-hba-conf.html

Comment: Thats exactly what i figured out.. thanks for that tip. Will keep in mind @Jo